# how to find 32bit or 64 bit in linux

Tags: hardware

hi guys i am new to this field.I have a doubt related with, whether my Desktop is 32bit 0r 64 bit.See here when i was trying with console using this command in Linux #arch its displaying like i686.When i trying with this command #dmidecode -t processor its displaying like characteristics:64-bit capable.
so here which one is correct and what is the difference between them
.I am confused with 32 or 64bit.Need help.Thanks in advance

Comment: i686 means 32 bit version OS and x86_64 is 64 bit version OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64bit processor can run 64bit operating system or 32bit operating system. 32bit processor can run only 32bit operating system. So you are running less capable operating system, then your processor can.

Comment: Thanks dude .This one gave me the solution and now i really understand in my 64 bit processor i installed 32bit operating that's why it is giving like that.